# Is it possible to POST content from SMS to Amazon S3 bucket in AMPScript?

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, ampscript, aws, amazon-s3

Has anyone tried to use the AMPScript `HTTPPost`function to upload message content to amazon S3?

```
Set @AWSpost = HttpPost(@url, "text/html", @messageInfo)]%%
```

I'm wondering if I can pass in parameters to that POST that can authorize a post with AWS S3 or if I should just post the content to my WebApp and have an Api controller handles the post and uploads the content to AWS S3.

Any input or examples would be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much for taking the time to help me out and please let me know if you need anything more from me.

Answer (score 2):

Part of the signing of the API call required for AWS requires signing using HMAC SHA256. You'll not be able to do that from AMPScript, so I'd suggest getting your web app or other to act as a proxy or do the post directly from there.

Comment: That makes sense. I will try to make AMPScript post to a Web API controller in my application and have that controller handle the uploading to AWS